# Making Seurat object from a processed file

Tags: r, seurat, 10x-genomics

I have downloaded `log2(TPM/10+1)` values of `11,548 genes` and `9609 cells` from `GSE146026` (10x) in `tsv format` as the raw data is not available

I see patient IDs, cell barcodes, genes, even assigned clusters are here

```
> dput(head(a[1:5,1:5]))
structure(list(Cell_ID = c("10x_barcode", "patient", "time", 
"sample_ID", "clst"), X10x_1 = c("10x_3288_t1_AAACATACCTTCCG-1", 
"5", "1", "3288.1", "1"), X10x_2 = c("10x_3288_t1_AAACATACTCCTAT-1", 
"5", "1", "3288.1", "1"), X10x_3 = c("10x_3288_t1_AAACATTGAACTGC-1", 
"5", "1", "3288.1", "1"), X10x_4 = c("10x_3288_t1_AAACATTGCTGACA-1", 
"5", "1", "3288.1", "2")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

I want to make a Seurat object of that but really I don't know how to do that

I have tried this

```
    CreateSeuratObject(getwd(),gene.column = 2,cell.column = 1,unique.features = TRUE,strip.suffix = FALSE)
```

But get the following error:

```
Error in CreateAssayObject(counts = counts, min.cells = min.cells, min.features = min.features) : 
  No cell names (colnames) names present in the input matrix
```

Anybody have ever dealt with such a case to help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you need is `CreateSeuratObject()` and not `Read10X()` as you start from TPMs.